# Problema SharedPreferences en Java

Tags: java, android

Hola tengo el siguiente código. Me arroja un error en el SharedPreferences

> The method getSharedPreferences is undefined for the type unique

He intentado de todo pero nada me ha funcionado.

Si me pudieran ayudar se los agradecería en el alma.

````
ScrollView scrollV = new ScrollView(getApplicationContext()); scrollV.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));


scrollV.addView(v2);


jmag1.setView(scrollV);

jmag1.setCancelable(false);

Button btn1 = (Button) v2.findViewById(R.id.button1);

 class unique 
{ 
EditText c2 = (EditText) v2.findViewById(R.id.et2);

EditText c3 = (EditText) v2.findViewById(R.id.et3);

String p1 = c2.getText().toString().trim();

String p2 = c3.getText().toString().trim();

SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getSharedpreferences("mp",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();

}

btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){ 
public void onClick(View v2){  

unique s = new unique();

    if(s.p1.length() == 6 && s.p2.length() == 6){

    if(s.p1.equals(s.p2)){

s.editor.putString("VB", " TRUE");
s.editor.putString("CLAVE", s.p2);
s.editor.commit();

showMessage("Son iguales"); 
        }else{
            showMessage("No Son iguales, intentalo de nuevo.");
}

}else{
            showMessage("La contreseña debe ser de 6 dígitos");
}


} 
});

Switch sw1 = (Switch) v2.findViewById(R.id.switch1);```
````

Comment: ¿El código que anexas es de un Fragment? por cierto es "getSharedPreferences" y no "getSharedpreferences" es seguramente el problema, si es un error tipográfico este tipo de preguntas se cierra por la siguiente razón: "Parece ser un problema que no se puede reproducir o que contiene errores tipográficos." , saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estoy seguro si pudiese ser por lo siguiente pero, intenta poniendo la mayúscula de "Preferences" en tu código.

Donde:

```
getActivity().getSharedpreferences("mp",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Cambia:

```
getActivity().getSharedPreferences("mp",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

En Android los métodos y funciones son muy sensibles a las mayúsculas y minúsculas, así que imagino que pudiese ser eso.